# Which analyze-suspend should I foresee for a checkbox in a temporary table inside a browser?

Tags: openedge, progress-4gl

I am working with Progress-4GL, release 11.6, appBuilder and procedure editor. I can't upgrade to a more recent IDE.

I have created a temporary table, containing a `LOGICAL` field (shown as a checkbox), and I'm showing the values of those checkboxes inside a browser object.

Now I need the following piece of source code:

```
ON LEAVE OF temptable.checkbox_attribute IN BROWSE browser_object
DO: ...
END.
```

The problem is: now I would like to open this file in appBuilder, but as there are no `ANALYZE-SUSPEND` and `ANALYZE-RESUME` lines around it, the appBuilder will remove those lines.
In order to avoid this, I'd like to write those lines myself, but how can I do that?

For your information: in the appBuilder it is only possible to add events to existing statical objects, so adding events to temporary tables can't be done.

I already tried copying such a line from another event, but as the mentioned `_CONTROL ...` objects don't correspond, this doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need &ANALYZE-SUSPEND / &ANALYZE-RESUME. Just put the whole trigger in the main block of the program, after

```
&ANALYZE-SUSPEND _UIB-CODE-BLOCK _CUSTOM _MAIN-BLOCK B-table-Win
```

(Or just navigate to section Main Block in the Section Editor of the AppBuilder.)
The AppBuilder does not recognize this as a separate user interface trigger.